# Obj c - Parse Issue on if statement

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

Im getting a 'parse issue: Expected expression' error on the 'else if' line and can't work out why, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
if (sender == self.slider)
    self.textField.text = string;
NSString* string2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", (440 * pow(2, (sender.value-69.0)/12.0))];
    self.textField2.text = string2;

else if (sender == self.slider2)
   self.textField2.text = string;
string2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", (log2f (sender.value / 440) * 12) + 69]; 
self.textField.text = string2;
```

Comment: You need braces (`{ }`) in the `if` statement and its `else if`

Comment: Exactly the same problem you'd have with C or Java, and you should be pretty familiar with one or the other before attempting Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

As commenter said, you need braces:

```
if (sender == self.slider){
    self.textField.text = string;
NSString* string2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", (440 * pow(2, (sender.value-69.0)/12.0))];
    self.textField2.text = string2;

} else if (sender == self.slider2){
   self.textField2.text = string;
string2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", (log2f (sender.value / 440) * 12) + 69]; 
   self.textField.text = string2;

}
```